# Checking latest versions of dependencies in package.json file

Tags: excel, npm, package.json, npx, npm-check-updates

I want to prepare an excel sheet with the current installed versions and latest versions of dependencies in my `package.json` file like this:

[image]

The current versions I can get from the package.json file but I am not sure how to get the latest version of all the packages. Also, I have tried running `npm-check-updates` in the console but unlike the name suggests, it upgrades all the versions instead of only checking the latest versions. Moreover, copying and pasting from console does not look good as I need to use "Data to Column" in the excel file.

Comment: If you `cd` to your project directory and run the [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ls) command that will more accurately indicate the current version of a package you have installed, more so than obtaining it from what's listed in _package.json_, e.g. `npm ls @angular/core`. To obtain the latest version of a package utilize the [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-view) command, e.g. running `npm view @angular/core version` indicates the _latest_ version available for `@angular/core`.

Comment: @RobC is there a command that can help list latest versions of all the dependencies at once instead of doing one by one? There is a huge list of dependencies installed.